# Error: Invalid from email address - SendGrid

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid, nodemailer

I've been using SendGrid.com to handle password reset email requests for a few years without issue. I haven't changed anything and for the last two days all users have been getting an "**Error: Invalid from email address**" error on all email requests.

**This is happening on all valid email addresses.**

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this would randomly start happening. SendGrid seems to be running without issue on their end. I am waiting to get feedback from Sendgrid.

My set up:

```
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    var sgTransport = require('nodemailer-sendgrid-transport');

    app.post('/forgot', usernameToLowerCase, function(req, res, next) {
    async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
    crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
    var token = buf.toString('hex');
    done(err, token);
    });
    },
    function(token, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
    req.flash('error', 'No account with that email address exists.');
    return res.redirect('/forgot');
    }
    
    user.resetPasswordToken = token;
    user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour
    
    user.save(function(err) {
    done(err, token, user);
    });
    });
    },
    function(token, user, done) {
    
    
    var options = {
    auth: {
    api_user: '=====',
    api_key: '======'
    }
    }
    
    var client = nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport(options));
    
    var email = {
    from: 'BusinessName',
    to: user.username,
    subject: 'Reset Your Password',
    text:'====='
    };
    
    client.sendMail(email, function(err) {
    req.flash('success', 'An email was sent to ' + user.username + ' with further instructions.' );
    done(err);
    });
    }
    ], function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.redirect('/forgot');
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same error message "Invalid from email address" in SendGrid library for php. It seems that SendGrid has made some incompatible changes to their api regarding `from` field format.

In my case the `from` field does not accept single email address anymore, so I've changed it to an array with single email address and it worked.

```
from: ['some@example.com']
```

If it doesn't help, try to compare the request coming from the transport wrapper with SendGrid documentation https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/index.html.
I am not sure how the wrapper works, but the expected format of `from` field in api seems like this:

```
"from": {
  "email": "example@example.com"
}
```

Comment: That did the trick thank you so much for the input! I have had the "from" email set to just my business name "BusinessName". Not even a valid email address for ages. Something clearly changed on SendGrids end. Changing it to ["BusinessName@gmail.com"] in an array, Solved the issue. Thanks!!